# How to properly manage parent:child relationships

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Card, by default, assumes the size of its  child. So,  if  we want to change the size of that card, then we also need to change the size of its child.

Text, on the other hand, is a  widget. Which, by default, only takes as much space as this text needs. Therefore, if you want to change the size of Text, you need to also change the size of its parent. Since the Card depends on the child and the Text depends on the parent.

Comment: Code as text: correct. Code as screenshots: incorrect. Code as *photos of screens*: borderline criminal.

Comment: @fawad which explanation? the screenshot or the paragraph below, please make your question more clear and quote the explanation, and please post a code not screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Card by default does not have any height or width. The width/height depends on the Child or the Card. In the screenshot, the child here is Text() Widget. The Text widget takes as much space as it's font size. So more the font size is, the larger will be Card.

The last part of the explanation is incorrect. You can't change parent size here as "Card" widget does not has any size properties. So if u want bigger card and small text, use "Container" Widget instead of Card. Almost all developers use Container only to create Card. Container has more feature then a card has.

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  child: Material(
    elevation: 5,
    child: Text("Chart!"),
  ),
)
```